# Windows installer silently skips over component marked as 'Local'

Tags: windows, windows-installer, dynamics-business-central, setup.exe

I'm installing [Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-365/products/business-central) via an automated process, which executes the `setup.exe` as part of a PowerShell script. In a nutshell, it does this:

```
$argList = '/Quiet', "/config config.xml", "/log my.log"
Start-Process "setup.exe" -ArgumentList $argList -Wait -PassThru -NoNewWindow
```

I tested the installation many times as my own user on a test host and everything looks fine. The log file also contains proof that all components are installed (the .net warning seems to be harmless, it detects that a slightly newer version is already installed):

```
SUCCESS: Package Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central Setup Components executed sucessfully.
SUCCESS: Package IIS prerequisites for Web Server Components executed sucessfully.
WARNING: Package Microsoft .NET Core Windows Server Hosting executed with warnings. See detailed message above.
SUCCESS: Package Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central Server Components executed sucessfully.
SUCCESS: Package Web Server Components executed sucessfully.
```

However, when the same script is executed with a technical service account, the installation silently skips over the `WebClient` component, although it is clearly enabled as `Local` in the `config.xml`:

```
<Component Id="WebClient" State="Local" ShowOptionNode="yes"/>              <-- this one!
<Component Id="SQLServerDatabase" State="Absent" ShowOptionNode="yes"/>
<Component Id="SQLDemoDatabase" State="Absent" ShowOptionNode="yes"/>
<Component Id="ServiceTier" State="Local" ShowOptionNode="yes"/>
<Component Id="Pagetest" State="Local" ShowOptionNode="yes"/>
<Component Id="DevelopmentEnvironment" State="Absent" ShowOptionNode="yes"/>
```

Everything in the installation works exactly the same with the technical user, the logs are all equivalent up to the point where `WebClient` should be added. But the following expected lines never appear in the log:

```
Configuring package. Id = 'WebClient'
MSI log file set to: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\setup.wix.msi.3.log
Done configuring package. Id = 'WebClient' ReturnCode = 0
[...]
SUCCESS: Package Web Server Components executed sucessfully.
```

Is there anything that can cause a Windows installer to skip over a component?
Is there any privilege or configuration that our technical user might be missing?